# how to say "I expect to finish sth by the end of June"?

Tags: tense

I am writing a cover letter and want to say that I expect to finish my master thesis by the end of June. Is it true:

> "I **expect** to finish my thesis by the end of June"

or

> "I **expected** to finish my thesis by the end of June"

Comment: The first one is correct just to answer your question

Comment: If by *sth* you mean to say *something*, please write out the actual word.

Answer (score 2):

The word "expect" is present tense while the word "expected" is past tense. Therefore, if you use the word "expect" you are saying that at this moment your expectation is that you will be finished by June. If you use the word "expected" then you are saying that at some point in the past your expectation was that you would be finished in June, but that is no longer your expectation (either because you realized that it will take longer than you thought, or because the deadline has already passed).

If you are trying to convey the first point then use the word "expect". If you are trying to convey the second point then use the word "expected".

Answer (score 0):

In May you would say "I expect to finish in June". In July, when you didn't manage to finish, you say "I expected to finish in June", meaning that you were overly optimistic, and it didn't happen.

You could also say "I'm expected to finish in June", which means other people expect you to finish, or that you are supposed to finish in June.

Answer (score -1):

The first example is good for your purpose.

> I expect to finish my thesis by the end of June.

You would use "expected" if you promised that you will finish it by the end of June, but then something changed and you won't be able to finish it by then.